# Morrey Spaces are Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I'm working with Morrey spaces, which are the spaces
$$L^{p,\lambda}(\Omega):= \left\{ u \in L^1_{loc}(\Omega): \sup_{x \in \Omega, r > 0} r^{-\lambda}\int_{B(x,r)\cap \Omega}|u(y)|^pdy< \infty\right\},$$
equipped with the norm
$$\left\|u\right\|_{p,\lambda} = \left(r^{-\lambda}\int_{B(x,r)\cap\Omega}|u(y)|^p\right)^{1/p}.$$
Some notes (for example http://w3.ualg.pt/~ssamko/dpapers/files/251_Morrey_overview.pdf) said that they are Banach spaces with above norms. However, I cannot find a reference for proof of the case $\Omega$ is unbounded.

I want to ask for a book or a publish, where I can find the proof. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't have a reference right now, but does it matter for a proof whether $\Omega$ is bounded or not? You could read the proof for bounded case to check this, and then refer to it, saying the same proof works for unbounded.